# Second-to-last occurrence of delimiter-split string

Tags: regex, string, substring, delimiter, pcre

What is the regex to extract second-to-last substring when the string is to be split by specified delimiter?

E.g., the delimiter is comma `,` - I would only like to match words "matchX".

```
a,b,match1,c
a,match2,b
match3,a
match4,
,,match5,a
,,match6,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be just a match with a negative lookahead assertion, and exclude matching newlines before asserting the end of the string.

```
\w+(?=,[^,\n]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/beJeVp/1)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case, one of the below can do it.

When the substring contains any symbol including spaces:

```
([^,\n]+),[^,]*$
```

When the substring contains only alphanumeric characters and underscore `_`:

```
(\w+),[^,]*$
```

When the substring contains only alphanumeric characters:

```
([[:alnum:]]+),[^,]*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/e987Xr/1